# Sum of tuples in python using zip()

Tags: python

```
  'ABX': [(1, 9)],
  'ABD': [(4, 1)],
  'ABY': [(9, 1), (10, 1), (2, 2)],
  'ABR': [(8, 2), (8, 3)]}
```

Above is the sample python dictionary,  I wanted to get output such that tuple elements in the dictionary should be added and make it has single tuple. Below is the required output

```
  'ABX': [(1, 1)],
  'ABD': [(4, 1)],
  'ABY': [(21, 4)],
  'ABR': [(16, 5)]}
   }
```

I tried with below code for element (ABR) in dict0 in python shell

```
    >>>test = [sum(x) for x in zip([ i for i in dict['ABR'])]
    Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
    TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'tuple'
```

```
[ i for i in dict['ABR'] ]
```

this gives a tuple , how can I iterate in zip() ?
Any other solution would be very use full

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a dict comprehension with each value produced from a sum of a generator expression:

```
{k: tuple(sum(t) for t in zip(*l)) for k, l in dict0.items()}
```

This returns:

```
{'ABX': (1, 9), 'ABD': (4, 1), 'ABY': (21, 4), 'ABR': (16, 5)}
```

Comment: Glad to be of help. Can you mark this answer as accepted if you find it to be correct? (Click on the grey check mark next to the answer.)

Answer (score 1):

using basic `for` loop

```
import operator
d={ 'ABX': [(1, 9216)],
  'ABD': [(4, 15360)],
  'ABY': [(9, 11264), (10, 1024), (14, 451584)],
  'ABR': [(18, 738304), (9, 369664)]}
```

Now updating the dictionary with summed values

```
for k,v in d.items():
    sum_tup =(0,0)
    for i in v:
         sum_tup=tuple(map(operator.add, sum_tup, i))
    d[k]=sum_tup
```

**Output**

```
{'ABD': (4, 15360),
 'ABR': (27, 1107968),
 'ABX': (1, 9216),
 'ABY': (33, 463872)}
```